# how to use substring function and what does this mean?

Tags: javascript

so i'm currently trying to figure out what the code below will output. I'm confused by the substr function so if you could explain that it would be amazing. Thanks

```js
    function getAttackString() {
    var foo = "d32329b34";
    var bar = "x38h309hj";
    return "The code is: "+(foo.substr(3,foo.length-6))+(bar.substr(2));
    }
    
    console.log(getAttackString());
```

Comment: substring will get you a part of the string

Comment: [`String.prototype.substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

Comment: And `foo.length` is unneccessary, you can simply remove that

Comment: So what would be the output of the string? Confused about that

Comment: Is there some reason that you can't run this code to see the output and to look at the documentation for **[`substr`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)**

Answer (score 0):

3298h309hj

foo.substr(3, foo.length - 6 )) => get the substring of foo that is 6 chars 
shorter than foo starting at char 3 = 329

bar.substr(2) => get the substring of bar that starts at char 2 and returns all of the chars = 8h309hj

```js
function getAttackString() {
var foo = "d32329b34";
var bar = "x38h309hj";
return "The code is: "+(foo.substr(3,foo.length-6))+(bar.substr(2));
}

console.log( getAttackString() );
```

Answer (score 0):

> The `substr()` method returns the characters in a string beginning at the specified location through the specified number of characters.

The syntax for this function is

```
str.substr(start[, length])
```

> `start`: Location at which to begin extracting characters. If a negative number is given, it is treated as strLength + start where strLength is the length of the string. For example, `str.substr(-3)` is treated as `str.substr(str.length - 3)`
>
> `length`: The number of characters to extract. If this argument is undefined, all the characters from start to the end of the string are extracted.

(https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/String/substr)

So applying it to your code:

```js
function getAttackString() {
  var foo = "d32329b34";
  var bar = "x38h309hj";
  return "The code is: " + foo.substr(3,foo.length-6) + bar.substr(2);
}
    
console.log(getAttackString());
```

The expression `foo.substr(3,foo.length-6)` is extracting `foo.length-6` (`9-6=3`) characters starting from the 4th character , `3`, resulting in `329`.

The expression `bar.substr(2)` is extracting all of the characters (since the second parameter, `length`, is undefined) starting from the 3rd character, `8`, resulting in `8h309hj`.

Put them together with the final expression and you get: `The code is: 3298h309hj`